# jsPDF use base pdf write on top

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a system build in PHP where I take a pdf and place it as a background and then on a second layer place text on top of it with coordinates. This makes that managing the two different parts are easy. Because the initial pdf is difficult to reproduce in html. So html2pdf is not an option. I tried it but because of all the different lines and sections and text the library cannot manage it.

[Base PDF example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JfjacHMuVsQu8n_b_NPYSIcd64bQ6z5_/view?usp=sharing)

Because of reasons I am now looking to replicate this functionality in javascript. So I was wondering if something similar is possible in jsPDF. Or any other library.

Comment: anyway to attract more people to a open question?

Answer (score 0):

After a long and tedious search I found that [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) is what I needed. They allow to pull in a existing pdf and alter it by writing ontop of it.

I did experience some issues with pulling in the pdf but that can be solved. It was mostly because of fetch() method. But they allow Base64 inport.